# Syntax highlighting on dynamic blog posts not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highlight.js

I'm making a blog using Vue and am using [vue-highlightjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-highlightjs) to add syntax highlighting to the code I will write in the blog posts. I'm just using a `textarea` in my admin panel to write the blog posts, so I have to manually type in the HTML I want displayed.

```
<textarea v-model="editorData" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
```

`editorData` is just a String. On the page where the blog posts are displayed, I grab the blog post from the server and display it in a BlogPost.vue component. Here is the code for that component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <pre v-highlightjs><code class="javascript">const s = new Date().toString()</code></pre>
    <h1 class="page-title">{{postTitle}}</h1>
    <div v-html="postBody"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import { baseUrl } from "@/strings";
export default {
  name: "BlogPost",
  data: function() {
    return {
      postTitle: "",
      postBody: ""
    };
  },

  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    axios.get(baseUrl + "/blogPosts/" + to.params.id).then(response => {
      next(vm => vm.setData(response.data));
    });
  },
  methods: {
    setData(data) {
      this.postTitle = data.title;
      this.postBody = data.content;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The `v-highlightjs` directive in the `pre` tag at the beginning of the template just tells the vue-highlightjs plugin to add syntax highlighting to the code inside.

The problem is that the hardcoded code in the `pre` tag at the beginning of the `div` is highlighted, but the dynamically loaded code in `postBody` is not highlighted. For example, if I type `<pre v-highlightjs><code class="javascript">const s = new Date().toString()</code></pre>` into my admin panel textarea then display the post in my BlogPost.vue page, it looks like this:

[image]

I don't know if vue-highlightjs doesn't highlight the code because it's dynamic or what. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

P.S. There's got to be a better way to create an admin panel where I can make blog posts that will show up with syntax highlighting when I type code. I tried CKEditor for a bit but found it really confusing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you don't want to use `v-html`. Try using `{{ postBody }}` instead

Comment: It was worth a shot, but using `postBody` doesn't render the HTML, it just prints the string exactly as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directive will not highlight updated code after the initial highlighting. To do so, you need to pass a variable to the `v-highlightjs` directive:

```
<pre v-highlightjs="postBody"><code class="javascript"></code></pre>
```

From [Vue.js Syntax Highlighting with Highlight.js](https://www.metachris.com/2017/02/vuejs-syntax-highlighting-with-highlightjs/):

> **Reacting to code updates**
>   `highlight.js` replaces the content of the code block. If using the directive as shown above, updating the source-code after the initial highlighting does not work anymore. To be able to update the code and highlight it again after an update, pass the variable directly into the v-highlightjs directive

Here's a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/digitaldrifter/wc3268sj/2/) modified from [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/metachris/1vz9oobc/).

If you need more control over the content that is highlighted, I would suggest using the `highlightjs` library itself rather than the directive and manually call `hljs.highlightBlock`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    post: null,
    posts: [
      `Phasellus luctus magna non sem fermentum, sed pulvinar ex blandit. Vestibulum id auctor neque. Etiam aliquam commodo sollicitudin. <pre><code class="javascript">var foo = bar</code></pre>Etiam cursus commodo neque, at semper dui vestibulum auctor.`,
      `Etiam non elit velit. <pre><code class="javascript">while (true) { console.log('test') }</code></pre>Vestibulum nec posuere lorem. Ut dolor ante, eleifend ut porttitor eu, faucibus non sapien.`,
      `Morbi eleifend ornare felis, vel vulputate nibh suscipit id. <pre><code class="javascript">const func = () = ({ foo: 'bar' })</code></pre>Phasellus luctus magna non sem fermentum, sed pulvinar ex blandit. Vestibulum id auctor neque. Etiam aliquam commodo sollicitudin.`
    ]
  }),
  beforeMount() {
    this.post = this.posts[0]
  },
  mounted() {
    this.highlightPost()
  },
  methods: {
    highlightPost() {
      document.querySelectorAll('code').forEach((block) => {
        hljs.highlightBlock(block)
      })
    },
    cycle() {
      const index = this.posts.indexOf(this.post)

      this.post = index === this.posts.length - 1 ? this.posts[0] : this.posts[index + 1]

      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.highlightPost()
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.9.0/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.9.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="cycle">Next Post</button>
  <p id="post-content" v-html="post"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: That does add highlighting to the code inside of the post, but what if I have parts that should just be rendered like normal HTML? What if the blog post looks like `<p>Content that should be displayed normally</p><code>some code in the post</code>` and only the stuff inside of the `code` tag should be highlighted? Right now doing `<pre v-highlightjs="postBody"><code class="javascript"></code></pre>` puts everything inside of a code block.

Comment: That being the case I'd use the highlightjs library directly and manually call `hljs.highlightBlock` each time the content is updated. I've updated the answer with an example.